# Calculate an arbitrary value based on a two points

Tags: linear-algebra, relations

I am working in Fruity Loops studio, and funnily enough, I need to solve something with math. I want a way to calculate the track tempo I get based on an arbitrary value.

I know the following values give these tempos:

```
 60 BPM = 0.09765625
150 BPM = 0.27343
180 BPM = 0.33203125
```

So say I want figure out a method of finding an arbitrary number, and I already know those three values. What would the formula look like? My math skills could really use some work, but that's not important here.

Comment: @Smurfton I don't know if it is linear, but I have figured out that 150 BPM is equal to 0.27343. Can we know by that if it is linear? I'm not sure what unit it is, but I think it is percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we suppose that the relationship between the tempo and the output value is **linear**, then we can easily determine an equation for the line. I used a [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line+through+%2860%2C0.09765625%29+and+%28180%2C+0.33203125%29) to find the equation, rather than breaking out 'ye olde calculator. Letting the $x$-axis represent BPM and the $y$-axis represent your parameter, it gave me $y=0.00195313x-0.019313$. So you can evaluate this equation for $x=150$ BPM to get $y=0.2734382$.

Now, this only holds if the relation is a **straight line**. If you have any information about whether the relationship is linear or not (for example, a third ordered pair), you should add it in, and we might be able to give you a better approximation.

ETA: looks like you got the same answer as me for the parameter corresponding to 150 BMP. I would say that's pretty good evidence that your relationship is linear. Therefore, you can use the above equation to calculate the parameter (percentage?) for any tempo.

Comment: I am a little confused. When I try this equation: I get a slightly different number. I get `0,291015625` instead of the expected `0.2734382`. I tried the following in my code: `y = slope * x - slope`. Did I read this wrong?

Comment: You don't want to use $y=$ slope $x -$ slope. The equation of a line is $y=mx+b$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the **y-intercept**, or the place where the line crosses the $y$-axis. (The $y$-intercept is the theoretical value of your parameter when your tempo is $0$ BPM). The slope, on the other hand, describes how steep a line is. Note that in the above equation, the slope is $0.00195313$, while the $y$-intercept is $0.019313$.

Comment: I am still confused. What does `mx` directly translate to? `m * x` ?

Comment: Yes, $mx$ means the same as $m*x$ or $m$ "times" $x$

Comment: Now I get a really weird number. When I do `y = m * x + b`, I get this: `0,3122825` when i set `x = 150`. Any ideas? My other variables are: `m = 0.00195313`, `b = 0.019313`

Comment: Oops, I should have said $b= -0.019313$ as in my original answer.

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks for the help! Got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a linear function (it's shaped like a line), the first thing to do is find the slope:

$m = {{y_2 - y_1} \over {x_2 - x_1}}$

$m ={ {.33203125 - .09765625} \over {180 BPM - 60 BPM}} = 0.001953125 $

Since we also have a point, using the point-slope formula is most convenient here.

$y-y_1 = m (x-x_1)$
$y - 0.09765625 = 0.001953125(x - 60)$
$y = 0.001953125 x - 0.01953125$

In this equation, x is the BPM, and y is your output. You'll find that this holds for other points, and the method of finding the answer used here will work for any line.